# Quels mots doivent être au pluriel dans des expressions du genre « types de document » ou « opérateurs de carte de crédit » ?

Tags: prépositions, pluriel, accord

Dans la phrase suivante:

> Nous allons gérer plusieurs types de document dans ce nouveau système.

Est-ce que « document » devrait être au pluriel ?

Doit-on observer la même règle lorsqu'on veut simplement titrer une liste quelconque ? Comme par exemple :

> Liste des opérateurs de carte de crédit supportés.

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9385, https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7895

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C'est une question de lecture, ou de point de vue :

> Nous allons gérer plusieurs types de document dans ce nouveau système.

est correct lorsque l'on considère qu'un document est une entité :

- Nous allons gérer plusieurs types de [ n'importe quel document | (modèle de) document ] dans ce nouveau système.

donne le point de vue l’informaticien, alors que l'utilisateur verra chacun des documents (des objets) de différents modèles qu'ils gèrent.

De même pour les cartes de crédit :

- le fournisseur de (l'entité) 'carte de crédit',

est aussi un fournisseur d'objets :

- le fournisseurs de (ses différentes) cartes de crédit.

Answer (score 1):

La préposition « de » introduit souvent un nom sans article. L'accord du nom étant parfois difficile à trouver, il faut décomposer l'expression, c'est-à-dire essayer de la reformuler afin de faire apparaître le déterminant.

Dans le premier cas nous avons :

> Nous allons gérer plusieurs types de document dans ce nouveau système.

qui peut être reformulé comme suit :

> Nous allons gérer plusieurs documents de différents types dans ce nouveau système.

Ce qui implique que « document » doit être au pluriel c'est à dire

> Nous allons gérer plusieurs types de documents dans ce nouveau système.

Dans le second cas l'expression :

> Liste des opérateurs de carte de crédit supportés

peut être reformulée comme suit :

> Liste des opérateurs dont les cartes de crédit sont supportées.

Dans ce dernier cas il faut remarquer que « carte » est au pluriel parce que nous avons affaire à différents opérateurs.

Answer (score 1):

D'une façon générale, ce type de question peut être résolu simplement pour les francophones natifs comme la plupart l'ont appris à l'école primaire. Il suffit de remplacer le mot en question par un autre pour lequel le nombre est perceptible et de choisir la phrase qui correspond à l'interprétation recherchée. Par exemple, en remplaçant *document* par *journal*, on peut se faire une idée plus claire de ce qu'on perçoit avec chacune des formules.

> Nous allons gérer plusieurs types de document dans ce nouveau système.
> Nous allons gérer plusieurs types de documents dans ce nouveau système.
>
> Nous allons gérer plusieurs types de journal dans ce nouveau système.
> Nous allons gérer plusieurs types de journaux dans ce nouveau système.